# WHAT is the output of print(0x1e1) in Lua? And Why?

Tags: lua

`print(0x1e1)` will print 481 in Lua, but I don't know why. Can anyone please help me understand?

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: If my answer solves your problem please selects it as answer rather than just upvoting (35 points vs 10 points in StackOverflow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because 481 (decimal) is 1e1 (hexadecimal).

The `0x` prefix means the number is hexadecimal, or base 16.

No prefix means the number is decimal, or base 10.

## Formatting

`print` will format numbers as decimal by default.

To print numbers in a specific base:

```
# As decimal
print(string.format("%d", 0x1e1))   # Output: 481
print(0x1e1) # Output: 481

# As hexadecimal
print(string.format("%x", 0x1e1))   # Output: 1e1
```

Comment: I still don't understand to be honest! 1e1 is 1x10^1 right? which is equal to 10. then print(0x1e1) ==> print(0x10) ==>16(decimal). Then how 481?

Comment: No sir. `e` in this context is not scientific notation but rather the `e` **digit**. In hexadecimals (base 16) digits go from 0 to 16: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
A (10), B (11), C (12), D (13), E (14), F (15). 0x10 is 16. 0x100 is 256

Comment: Thanks now I got it :D